# How to close all terminals with a bash script that effectively presses Cntrl+Shift+Q in each terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I often have many terminals open, some of which are running important processes (e.g. servers) and others which are not running anything and can be closed. The 'important' ones bring up prompts for confirmation if you press `Cntrl`+`Shift`+`Q` in them, like the one shown below.

[image]

I would like to have a (bash) script which closes all terminals but leaves the 'important' ones in the mode shown above. From https://askubuntu.com/questions/608914/closing-all-instances-of-terminal-at-once-cleanly, I obtained the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool search --class "terminal" | while read id
do
      xdotool windowactivate "$id" &>/dev/null
      xdotool key ctrl+shift+q
      sleep 0.2
done
```

However, I found after running the script that some 'unimportant' terminals still remained open. Is there perhaps a bug in the script above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another way to do this is to kill any idle `bash` processes, that is, those with no subprocesses. this should also close their parent terminal windows. it will run much faster than the `xdotool` + `sleep 0.2` method.

here is how i can see process trees for my `bash` processes:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -r -n1 pstree -p -c
```

output:

```
bash(1470)───startx(1546)───xinit(1568)─┬─Xorg(1569)─┬─{Xorg}(1570)
                                        │            ├─{Xorg}(1571)
                                        │            └─{Xorg}(1572)
                                        └─dwm(1575)
bash(1582)
bash(4004)
bash(4125)
bash(28105)───nvim(17279)─┬─R(17956)─┬─{R}(17958)
                          │          ├─{R}(17959)
...
```

the first and last `bash`s here have subprocesses and i don't want to kill them. the middle three can safely be killed, which will also close their parent terminal windows. first, i'll select only those by filtering out any lines with a "`-`":

```
pgrep bash | xargs -r -n1 pstree -p -c | grep -v \-
```

output:

```
bash(1582)
bash(4004)
bash(4125)
```

next, i'll use `grep` again to include only the process id numbers:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -r -n1 pstree -p -c | grep -v \- | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

output:

```
1582
4004
4125
```

finally, kill them:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -r -n1 pstree -p -c | grep -v \- | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | xargs -r kill
```

Comment: This is indeed much faster, because you also don't have to press "Cancel" in every window you don't want to close.

Comment: I would add ```xargs -r kill``` to the last step. If there are no idle terminals, it would execute kill with no arguments which ends up writing the help to the ```kill``` command. Note that this is a GNU extension.