# How to close all terminal either running nothing or iPython from a bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

The number of terminals I run tends to proliferate, and most of them are not important, by which I mean they are running either nothing or iPython.

In one of my previous questions, [How to close all terminals with a bash script that effectively presses Cntrl+Shift+Q in each terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406591/how-to-close-all-terminals-with-a-bash-script-that-effectively-presses-cntrlshi), a user named [webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563960/webb) explained how to close all terminals with no subprocesses:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c | grep -v \- | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | xargs kill
```

I would like to adapt this bash script somewhat to also select the IDs of processes running iPython.

**What I've tried so far**

As an example, one output of

```
pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c
```

looks like this:

```
bash(793)───ipython(847)───{ipython}(854)
bash(1787)───ipython(2061)───{ipython}(2062)
bash(6018)───ipython(6052)───{ipython}(6053)
bash(6810)───python(13796)───python(15653)───{python}(15657)
bash(7197)───docker-compose(20923)───docker-compose(20924)─┬─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           ├─{docker-compose}(2+
                                                           └─{docker-compose}(2+
bash(8629)───ipython(19746)─┬─{ipython}(19748)
                            ├─{ipython}(19762)
                            ├─{ipython}(19763)
                            ├─{ipython}(19764)
                            ├─{ipython}(19765)
                            ├─{ipython}(19766)
                            ├─{ipython}(19767)
                            └─{ipython}(19768)
bash(9945)───ipython(31376)─┬─{ipython}(31377)
                            ├─{ipython}(31391)
                            ├─{ipython}(31392)
                            ├─{ipython}(31393)
                            ├─{ipython}(31394)
                            ├─{ipython}(31395)
                            ├─{ipython}(31396)
                            └─{ipython}(31397)
bash(15906)───ipython(15974)───{ipython}(15976)
bash(16302)───xargs(19015)───pstree(19027)
bash(17377)───ipython(17407)───{ipython}(17409)
bash(17797)
bash(22210)───node(26380)─┬─{V8 WorkerThread}(26382)
                          ├─{V8 WorkerThread}(26383)
                          ├─{V8 WorkerThread}(26384)
                          ├─{V8 WorkerThread}(26385)
                          ├─{node}(26405)
                          ├─{node}(26406)
                          ├─{node}(26407)
                          └─{node}(26408)
bash(32331)───ipython(32359)───{ipython}(32361)
```

I'd like to select the pids of processes running nothing - in this case `17797` - and processes running `ipython`. As I understand it, I would like to replace the command

```
grep -v \-
```

after the second pipe, which selects every line without hyphens in it, to a pattern which select either such lines or lines containing both `bash` and `ipython`. As a first step I tried (based on the tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)

```
pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c | grep -v '(\-|ipython)'
```

but this seems not to work as the output contains the lines with `docker-compose`, for example. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to have a list of all terminals running bash as primary process and run ipython inside it? Then I think your regular expression is matching the wrong things, because of using grep instead of egrep. In any case, I did the following:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c | egrep "^(bash|.*[{]?ipython[}]?)\\([0-9]+\\)$" | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1
```

To achieve only bash processes without subprocesses, I added a match from start flag (^) and since ipython (or {ipython}) should be the last, added the match to end flag ($), then constructed a way to deal with the process numbers. This lists what you need.

Make life easy using cut to list the actual parent pids (so the processes needing actual killing in your case)

Comment: One additional note: one of the results of `pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c` is `bash(4090)───ipython(4116)───{ipython}(4117)`, but I've noticed that `kill 4090` by itself doesn't close the window; one needs `kill -9 4090`. So the full command (which I've added to my `.bashrc` file) is: `alias cls="pgrep bash | xargs -n1 pstree -p -c | egrep '^(bash|.*[{]?ipython[}]?)\\([0-9]+\\)$' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1 | xargs kill -9"`.